# costmap_2d expects non-existing include dir

Tags: navigation, catkin-make, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04.
When I call a catkin_make after cloning https://github.com/DLu/navigation_layers into my catkin_ws/src, I get the following error:

```
 +++ processing catkin package: 'range_sensor_layer'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation_layers/range_sensor_layer)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/costmap_2d/cmake/costmap_2dConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'costmap_2d' specifies '/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi' as an include
  dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory
  nor in '/opt/ros/kinetic//usr/include/hdf5/openmpi'.  Ask the maintainer
  'David V.  Lu!! <davidvlu@gmail.com>, Michael Ferguson
  <mferguson@fetchrobotics.com>' to fix it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  navigation_layers/range_sensor_layer/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

costmap_2d wants to have a library in this dir /usr/include/hdf5/openmpi, which does not exist. However, /usr/include/hdf5/ DOES exist, so does /usr/include/openmpi

Why does my ROS installation seem to differ from what costmap_2d expects? More important: How to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275978/costmap_2d-expects-non-existing-include-dir/) by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-15**:
I've seen issues like this happen occasionally if the include directory exists but is then removed; cmake caches the old path and then complains when it ceases to exist. You may want to try cleaning your workspace and rebuilding.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-15**:
In addition to what @ahendrix writes: `hdf5` is not a dependency of `range_sensor_layer`, nor (but I can't be certain) of one of its immediate dependencies.

It would appear the OpenMPI is then a dependency of `hdf5`, which does something strange (the include path doesn't make sense).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-15**:
It could be that `hdf5` comes in via the `pcl` dependency of `costmap_2d` ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/11d4431f4ca5e8983412d26db4d2c9b8e147a80d/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt#L25)).

Do you have a from-source build of PCL?

**Comment by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on 2017-11-15**:
@gvdhoorn I wrote an answer, maybe you can shed some light on the things that are still unclear for me. That way we might help future readers ;)

**Comment by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on 2017-11-15**:
@ahendrix Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried that before posting my qeustion here, it did nothing

**Comment by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on 2020-12-01**:
although this question is quite old, the problem just recently popped up again:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/1058

any ideas how to properly solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/2626 has something to do with the issue I was facing.

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-openmpi-dev
```

solved my immediate issues. However: here I got new problems about not finding libvtkproj4-6.2.so. I think there were some bugs around that as well, but the issues differ slightly:
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1594
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk6/+bug/1573234

This issue could be fixed by

```
sudo apt-get install libvtkproj-dev
```

But I knew I was on the wrong path trying to fix the symptoms of a problem instead of the source. The new issue that appeared was that catkin could not find costmap_2d anymore.

So: I fixed all my problems with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation
```

I don't know if the first 2 calls are completely overwritten by the apt-get update and reinstall of the navigation package (don't know if they had an effect in solving my problem). All I know is: it works now.

---

Originally posted by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) with karma: 48 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0